# Weight distribution in hands so that load between both hands is minimum

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph-algorithm, recursive-datastructures

Problem is you are given **n** number of weights, we need to distribute it in both the hands so that weight difference between hand is minimum.

Eg. Weights Given : 5 8 4
Good Distribution -
Right Hand : 5 4
Left Hand : 8

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Search "subset sum problem"

Comment: I really don't see the solution. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple strightforward algorithm to get you started.

```
Loop until all weights placed
    Place heaviest unplaced weight in left hand
    Loop until right hand weights > left hand weights
        Place heaviest unplaced weight less than difference in weights in hands in right hand
```

Comment: "Place heaviest unplaced weight less than difference in weights" what if there is no such weight? { 5 4 3 2 }

Comment: Then exit inner loop and continue with outer loop.

Comment: Then the answer is incorrect (5+3 and 4+2, should be 5+2 and 4+3).

Comment: The answer is not optimal.  I make no claim that the algorithm is optimal, just that gives a good start to the OP who seems to be struggling.  A simple algorithm easily implemented that gives sensible answers.

Comment: You should mention it in your answer. I suspect OP needs it for homework or coding competition, so nothing short of a perfect solution will fly.

Comment: I did so.  " get you started." means that.  I find that folks have trouble getting started, but once they see what can be done simply, then their brains get into gear.